# Twilio programmable chat: Invites expiry and user limit

Tags: php, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

This is regarding twilio's programmable chat invite to private channel. I have a few doubts:

1. Is there an expiry on the invite sent to the user (time limit within which it should be accepted)?
2. Is there a limit on the number of invites sent per channel, or number of invites sent to a user?

Thanks.